# DYMO Printing Accessing Network Printers

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dymo

I am using DYMO SDK (https://github.com/dymosoftware/dymo-connect-framework) to print labels from a project in ASP.NET MVC.

I am wondering how it is possible to access and print from a DYMO label printer that is on the network (LAN Cable) instead of USB.

I have added the network based printer through the DYMO Connect software and am able to print from there.

But in my code, it is unable to find any printers. Code Below:

```
function onload() {
        try {
            var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert("Couldn't Get Printer list");
            return;
        }

        if (printers.length == 0)
        {
            alert("No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.");
            return;
        }

        var printerName = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; ++i)
        {
            var printer = printers[i];
            alert(printer.name);
            if (printer.printerType == "LabelWriterPrinter")
            {
                printerName = printer.name;
                break;
            }
        }
```

The getPrinters() method finds printers that are connected via USB but I unable to access any printers that are strictly connected via LAN cable and showing on the network.

I am having trouble finding any help or samples online dealing with this issue. *Again, I am able to find the printer via USB with the getPrinters() method but unable to find the printer if it is connected via LAN cable on the network.*

Any help?

Comment: Can you print to this printer manually?  Do you have the network-based label printer defined in the printers for the OS?

Comment: This article may be helpful for determining if you already have the network printer set up or need to get it set up: https://support.evetpractice.com/hc/en-us/articles/205622917-How-do-I-set-up-and-install-a-DYMO-LabelWriter-printer-   See the section titled "**Adding a Network/Shared Printer**"

Comment: That link fixed my problem! Add that information as a solution below and I will accept it! Thanks so much.